# Android| How would I write this code to be more Object orientated?

Tags: android, oop

Hello I'm trying to use if statements to lunch different activity's. The following code does not seem very Object orientated. Does any one know a way in which I can make this more opp with out getting the error ("Variable intent may have not been initialized")

```
if (view.getId() == R.id.loadExistingBuildButton) {
        intent = new Intent(this, LoadExistingBuildActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    } else if (view.getId() == R.id.createNewBuildButton)
        intent = new Intent(this, CreateNewBuildActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Comment: You could consider refactoring the "getting" of the class type of the activity into a separate class (e.g. factory design pattern) - then your code looks like: startActivity(new Intent(this, BuildActivityFactory.getInstance().getClassType(view.getId())));

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
int id = view.getId();
if (id == R.id.loadExistingBuildButton) 
    startActivity(new Intent(this, LoadExistingBuildActivity.class);
else if (id == R.id.createNewBuildButton)
   startActivity(new Intent(this, CreateNewBuildActivity.class));
```

You can add an *else*  statement for a default case.

If you end up with a lot of if/else ifs you could consider using a method like

```
public void runIntentActivity(Activity someName)
{
      startActivity(new Intent(this, someName.class ));
}
```

so you can call

```
 runIntentActivity(LoadExistingBuildActivity)
```

instead of

```
 startActivity(new Intent(this, LoadExistingBuildActivity.class);
```

for each if/elseif